# Error when trying to print/email invoice

Tags: civicontribute

I have been trying to send old invoices to members. When printing to pdf, the file is essentially blank. When using the the email button I get the following error. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: CRM16923AnUnreliableMethodHasBeenUserToDeterminePaymentProcessorFromContributionPage in CRM_Contribute_BAO_Contribution->loadRelatedObjects() (line 2410 of /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/BAO/Contribution.php).
Notice: Undefined variable: invoiceNumber in CRM_Contribute_Form_Task_Invoice::printPDF() (line 569 of /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Task/Invoice.php).
Notice: Undefined property: DOMAttr::$value in Dompdf\Css\AttributeTranslator::translate_attributes() (line 233 of /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/Css/AttributeTranslator.php).
Notice: Undefined property: DOMAttr::$value in Dompdf\Css\AttributeTranslator::translate_attributes() (line 233 of /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/Css/AttributeTranslator.php).
Notice: Undefined property: DOMAttr::$value in Dompdf\Css\AttributeTranslator::translate_attributes() (line 233 of /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/Css/AttributeTranslator.php).
Notice: Undefined property: DOMAttr::$value in Dompdf\Css\AttributeTranslator::translate_attributes() (line 233 of /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/Css/AttributeTranslator.php).
Notice: Undefined property: DOMAttr::$value in Dompdf\Css\AttributeTranslator::translate_attributes() (line 233 of /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/Css/AttributeTranslator.php).
```

Error messages continue for quite awhile but are pretty similar and look to be related to the html to pdf converter.

Comment: What version of CiviCRM are you using?

Comment: 4.7.30, recent upgrade but I was seeing this issue prior

Comment: Well I added wkhtmltopdf and now it seems to be producing invoices just fine......